# Controlling y axis labels in a ggplot object for a time variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, axis

I'm attempting to plot a categorical variable on the x axis and a time on the y axis. I also have a categorical variable called run used to set line colour.

I have a time object created using the hms package object on the y axis. Even after stripping the ms from this object, they come back in when creating plots in ggplot.

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = category,y=plot_real_time),group = run,colour=run)) + 
  geom_line(linewidth=2)
```

creates the above plot. I don't need the .0000000 at the end.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Your y-axis may be categorical (strings), not a real "time" value. I think you need to convert it to something numeric, perhaps POSIXt, and then use `scale_y_datetime(date_labels="%H:%M:%S")` or similar.